# Google Custom search Api search by image url

Tags: google-api, google-custom-search

I want to search by image URL,but I didn't find any param where can pass image URL.

I pass image URL by param.

Like

https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyCxJUGIb_tevRKD-Kxxi57OM1f6dbRLwf4&cx=010407088344546736418:onjj7gscy2g&q=http://i.imgur.com/n4BhXEC.jpg

But get zero result, it's there anything wrong with my passing parameter?

If it can't.What API can do this and get Json response.

Comment: did it work for you? similar query doesn't work for me...

Comment: @jay did you ever make it work? I'm trying the same thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that the image you're looking for is too recent - Google doesn't update their archives constantly, so it might be worth waiting for a while. Additionally, you might have to publish your image, in order for it to appear on search engines.

EDIT: To clarify, nothing looks wrong with your API, it's just that the image hasn't been put on Google yet.